# DBUpdateException Entries only returning one item at a time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

Entity Framework 6.0; Visual Studio 15; SQL 2016;

DbUpdateException.Entries only generates one entry at a time.

I'm trying to add multiple items to a database.  When I call .SaveChanges() it generates an DbUpdateException due to Duplicate Key.  I try to eliminate the entries with duplicate key with the following code:

```
    public void  SaveDB(CEntities db) 
    {        
        bool savecompleted = false;
                while (!savecompleted)
                {
                    savecompleted = true;
                    try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException updateex)
                    {
                        foreach (DbEntityEntry item in updateex.Entries)
                            item.State = EntityState.Detached;
                        savecompleted = false;
                    }
               }
}
```

My understanding is that the DbUpdateException.Entries should have all the entities that failed.  I am only getting one entity at a time.  If I'm trying to add 500 entities and they are all duplicates, it will try to call .SaveChanges() 500 times.

Am I missing something

The code that adds the entities is:

```
   public void CreateActivity()
          {
            CEntities db = new CEntities();

            commentfield = GetComment();

            var scans = from x in dt.AsEnumerable() where x.Field<string>("Printid") != "0000000" group x by x.Field<string>("Printid") into p select new { printid = p.Key, Qty = p.Count(), date = p.Max(x => x.Field<DateTime>(timefield)) };
            foreach (var scan in scans)
            {
                int jobno =
                    (from x in db.ManifestDatas where x.PrintId == scan.printid select x.JobNo).FirstOrDefault();
                JobActivity activity = new JobActivity();
                activity.Activity = activityfield;
                activity.Employee = int.Parse(scan.printid);
                activity.ActivityDate = scan.date;
                activity.Quantity = scan.Qty;
                activity.JobNo = jobno;
                activity.Comment = commentfield;
                db.JobActivities.Add(activity);
            }

            SaveDB(db);

        }
```

Comment: Showing us the code that adds the entries to the context might shed some more light.

Comment: Which column is a primary key column here?

Comment: The primary key is multiple columns (Activity,Employee,ActivityDate,Jobno).  I understand why I'm getting the exception, what I'm trying to figure out is why `DbUpdateException.Entries` is only returning one item at a time.

Comment: With ef core 6 and sql server I get all entities that were tracked as a result of Entries-property. Even worse :/

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this in the actual implementation of Entity Framework. There is no **BulkInsert** method in EF. So, when SaveChanges executed, for each added entity it would be query into database like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[JobActivity]([Activity], [Employee], [ActivityDate], [Quantity], [JobNo], [Comment])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5) ...actual values for the first JobActivity
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[JobActivity]([Activity], [Employee], [ActivityDate], [Quantity], [JobNo], [Comment])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5) ...actual values for the second JobActivity
```

etc..
So, when the first error occured, it would be returned to the caller inside some Exception. If your error of violation primary key is a rare situation, you can leave your code as is. But the better choise is to generate primary key always unique and prevent inserting duplicates in the code.

Look at some libraries to allow bulk inserts to improve performance in EntityFramework if it's critical, for example [EntityFramework Extensions](http://www.entityframework-extensions.net).

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure that I was not doing anything wrong.  I actually went ahead and implemented a database lookup before adding entity. The main issue I have is that sometimes a duplicate data file is uploaded which can contain thousands of transactions which would all be duplicate.